# How can I rig an asymmetrical mesh?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I´d like to know if it is possible to rig an asymmetrical mesh avoiding the tedious weight paint process.  I want to automatically weight my mesh.
I used the automatic weight option to a fairly symmetric mesh and it worked perfectly,the thing is that when I added some asymmetries the program didn't include those asymmetries so they remained in its place without being affected by the deformation.

Answer (score 1):

Using automatic weights when assigning an armature to a mesh will assign weights to the existing mesh at that time, it will not automatically add weights to any modifications made after being applied.

By making changes to your mesh after rigging, you will need to manually weight paint the changes or redo the parenting with automatic weights to the new mesh. By reassigning the armature to the mesh you won't get duplicate armature modifiers or vertex groups, but you will most likely loose any manual adjustments you may have made to weight painting after doing automatic weights.

Comment: thaks a lot for your answer.Is there any way to find those vertices that cause "bone heating failed to find solution for one ore more bones"?